# Tertiary education expense for Expat children in Spain and Portugal?

Tags: student-visa, spain, portugal

I know that in some EU countries (such as Germany and Poland - **irrespective of the country of origin** - EU or Non-EU) tertiary education is absolutely free of charge if someone knows the native language up to C2 level.

Is there a similar policy for Portugal and Spain? Is language proficiency up to some level also a requirement?

Comment: This question was also asked on [Academia with a slightly different perspective](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/161400/is-tertiary-education-free-of-cost-in-spain-and-portugal) that may provide useful answers to those looking here.

Comment: @ouflak the initial wording of both posts is exactly the same